# Accessing method vars from inside arrow function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, google-cloud-firestore, arrow-functions

In my vuetify/vue.js appliction, i'm trying to read a firestore collection I've stored to calculate an average rating from all ratings stored there:

```js
function updateRating() {
  let firestoreQuery = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('ratings')
      .where('qrCodeId', '==', this.qrCode.id);

  let ratingsSum = 0;
  let ratingsAmountCounter = 0;

  firestoreQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      ratingsSum += doc.rating;
      ratingsAmountCounter++;
    });
  });
}
```

However, I can't access the `ratingsSum` and `ratingsAmountCounter` variables from inside my `forEach` arrow function. I've already tried using `this` or the `var _this = this` workaround, but both don't seem to work and eslint still reports:

> `'ratingsSum' is assigned a value but never used (no-unused-vars)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Accessing the variables like this looks ok. But since `firestoreQuery.get()` is **asynchronous**, it's unclear to me how/when you want to *read* `ratingsSum` and `ratingsAmountCounter`. The fact that you are using an arrow function is irrelevant.

Comment: @FelixKling hm, I haven't considered that - I wanted to increment them in the foreach to calculate the average value afterwards

Comment: You can do that... inside the `.then` callback. You can also *call* other functions and pass the average to it. But you cannot *return* the average value from `updateRating`. The best you can do is return the promise that `firestoreQuery.get().then(...)` returns.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I see what you're getting at - it seems like my original question is off-topic after all, then... I'll try to update it with my newest progress

Answer (score 1):

As the comments suggest, the problem here is that you have no code that actually *reads* `ratingsSum` and `ratingsAmountCounter`.  The error message is telling you that ESLint has triggered on the rule called "[no-unused-vars](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars)" to tell you about this.  Variables that are never read are probably a bug, or at least unnecessary code.

What you should probably do is return a promise to the caller so that they can get a hold of the values, whenever the asynchronous `get()` is complete and the values are computed.  For example:

```
function updateRating() {
  let firestoreQuery = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('ratings')
      .where('qrCodeId', '==', this.qrCode.id);

  let ratingsSum = 0;
  let ratingsAmountCounter = 0;

  return firestoreQuery.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      ratingsSum += doc.rating;
      ratingsAmountCounter++;
    });
    return { ratingsSum, ratingsAmountCounter }
  });
}
```

The caller of this function now receives a promise that resolves when the values are known, and they can be fetched out of the resolved object:

```
updateRating().then(result => {
  const { ratingsSum, ratingsAmountCounter } = result;
  // Now you can use ratingsSum and ratingsAmountCounter...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this might work, I have no way to test it since I don't know how to use vue but here goes

```
   async function getData(){
      return await firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('ratings')
          .where('qrCodeId', '==', this.qrCode.id)
          .get()
        }
    })
```

you can then do this:

```
getData().then(_querySnapshot => {
        var ratingsSum = 0
        var ratingsAmountCounter = 0
      _querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        ratingsSum += doc.rating;
        ratingsAmountCounter++;
      });
});
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!